# Invisible mode in Android studio (kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on a news app and I want my layout to become invisible when a user saves an article. Can anyone please tell me the right way to write this code?
2 things to note:
-when I run the app,the layout is visible in the "saved fragment"

- but then when I add "hideSavedMessage" right next to the code that updates the recyclerView and I run the app, the layout becomes invisible.

I want the layout to be invisible only when the user saves an article.

PS: I know how the visible and invisible mode works. I have used it before. My major problem is not knowing the right place to write the code. And by layout, I mean the text view and image view that appears on the screen.  I would appreciate any contributions. Thank you.

Here's my code

```
class SavedFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_saved) {

    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    lateinit var newsAdapter: SavedAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel
        setupRecyclerView()

        newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable("article", it)
            }
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_savedFragment_to_savedArticleFragment,
                bundle
            )
        }

        val itemTouchHelperCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
        ) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position =
                    viewHolder.adapterPosition//get position of item we deleted so that we swipe to left or right
                val article =
                    newsAdapter.differ.currentList[position]//from news adapter at the index of the position
                viewModel.deleteArticle(article)
                Snackbar.make(view, "Successfully deleted article", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .apply {
                        setAction("Undo") {
                            viewModel.saveArticle(article); hideSavedMessage()
                        }
                        show()
                    }

                val isAtLastItem = position <= 0
                val shouldUpdateLayout = isAtLastItem
                if (shouldUpdateLayout) {
                    showSavedMessage()
                }
            }

        }
        ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).apply {
            attachToRecyclerView(rvSavedNews)
        }



            viewModel.getSavedNews().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { articles ->
                newsAdapter.differ.submitList(articles)
            })
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        newsAdapter = SavedAdapter()
        rvSavedNews.apply {
            adapter = newsAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }

    }
    private fun hideSavedMessage() {
        savedMessage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        isArticleAdded = false
    }

    private fun showSavedMessage() {
        savedMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that code inside observer runs even at the beginning - when you run your app, right? If I understand your problem, you just have to manage to make the fun `hideSavedMessage()` not be running for the first time. You could for example instantiate a boolean in `onCreate()` and set it to false. Then, inside the observer, you could run the `hideSavedMessage()` only if that boolean is true - you would set it as true at the end of the observer. I hope you understand.